# JDB does not work on OS X 10.11

Tags: java, jdb

My Java version is 1.8.0_6. The JDB on my laptop can be started with a .class file, say MyClass.class. But after I type

> run

conmmand, JDB first gives me a prompt "run MyClass", then it is stuck for a while.
After that, it throws out the following error information,

> VM start exception: VM initialization failed for: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=promote.cache-dns.local:58261,suspend=y DebugMe
>
> ERROR: transport error 202: connect failed: Operation timed out
>   ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
>   JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:750]
>   FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
>
> Fatal error:
>   Target VM failed to initialize.

I have been compiling and running Java programs with "javac" and "java" properly in recent days. But I never used jdb before. Could anybody help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, it is likely that

your host name `promote.cache-dns.local` actually resolves to your external IP, but your firewall blocks it.

Quick fix for me was adding my hostname to `/etc/hosts` as `127.0.0.1 my-host-name`