# Debugging with jdb: transport err 202 get addrinfo

Tags: java, debugging, terminal, jdb

I'm to use the Java debugger in the terminal for Mac, and it seems to let me use it randomly. Sometimes it works, but other times it gives me this message:
run
run Lab5 commands1.txt
VM start exception: VM initialization failed for: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=Uzomas-MacBook-Air.local:49188,suspend=y Lab5 commands1.txt

ERROR: transport error 202: getaddrinfo: unknown host
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [:732]

I've researched solutions for this but never understood how to implement them, and I don't have enough reputation to comment so this is my only way

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50372800/2834978).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java JDB: ERROR: transport error 202: gethostbyname: unknown host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50344957/java-jdb-error-transport-error-202-gethostbyname-unknown-host)

Comment: I'm wondering how you actually do the solution?

Comment: It's explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50372800/2834978).

Comment: Yes, but how do you actually "Add the hostname mapping on hosts file keeping other names configured for that IP"? Do you simply type the statement below to the terminal, or is their something else you have to do?

Comment: You have to edit `/etc/hosts` file and add the mapping there. It's more related to OS administration (networking) than programming, that's why I didn't added the complete explanation.

Comment: How would you go about completing the second solution?

Comment: Depends on how you launch the jvm. Look at your IDE configuration for that.

Comment: Are you familiar with Intellij?

Comment: Never used it, sorry.