# ERROR: "Could not connect to socket..." when debugging xslt file with Xalan on Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, xslt-1.0, xalan

I am new in xslt with eclipse.

I have Eclipse IDE Enterprise version 2019-03 (4.11.0)

My debug configurations:

In "Processor" tab in "Debug Configuration" window I checked "Use specific processor", select "Xalan 2.7.1" from Processor list, and select "Interpertive".

Now, when I choose two files: xml and xsl to debugging, the console sttoped after below lines:

```
14:48:58,159 INFO  [main] DebugRunner  - debugger: org.eclipse.wst.xsl.xalan.debugger.XalanDebugger
14:48:58,186 DEBUG [main] DebugRunner  - requestPort: 59467
14:48:58,186 DEBUG [main] DebugRunner  - eventPort: 59468
14:48:58,186 DEBUG [main] DebugRunner  - generatePort: 59469
```

and after one minute I got error message window:

```
"Could not connect to socket 51095 after 60 attempts eclipse xalan"
```

What is the problem?

note: when I run (not debug) the same file with same configuration in "Run configuration" window, it worked correctly and created output file etc.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50344957/java-jdb-error-transport-error-202-gethostbyname-unknown-host/50372800#50372800).

Comment: I try to ping Patricks-iMac.local and recieved: Ping reruest could not host Patricks-iMac.local. Please check the name and try again.