# Payara 5 doesn't start in debug mode

Tags: payara

I'm new to Payara server and I tried just a simple *.war example to run it on Payara 5.193 Full version. If I start it with *asadmin start-domain* everything is fine. If I want to start it in debug mode with *asadmin start-domain --debug true* the windows console shows following:

*Waiting for domain1 to start .Error starting domain domain1.
The server exited prematurely with exit code 2.
Before it died, it produced the following output:
ERROR: transport error 202: gethostbyname: unknown host
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:750]*

The log file shows the start parameters like it does in "normal" mode and stucks.

The environment I use:

- Payara Server 193.1 Full
- JDK 1.8.0_131-b11
- Windows 10

I've also tried to switch off my Firewall.

Comment: Here is a similar problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50344957/java-jdb-error-transport-error-202-gethostbyname-unknown-host