# Remote debugging a gke pod running a java app in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, google-kubernetes-engine, remote-debugging

I know this question has been asked a lot, however none of the answers are resolving my issue(s).

Steps I take:

1. I add `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:8765` to the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS so it looks like this

```
- name: JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
          value: -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -Xms512m -Xmx1g -Xss256k -Dhttp.maxConnections=1000
            -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:8765 -Dlogging.config=classpath:logback-kube.xml
```

2. I run `kubectl port-forward [pod name] 8765:8765`
3. I make a debug configuration in IntelliJ that looks like the following screenshot
   [image: debug configuration]
4. run the debug configuration I just made.

This breaks on step 1. By breaks I mean the pod enters the CrashLoopBackOff state.

What am I missing? If I need to upload more info please let me know and I'll add it as soon as I can.

Container logs (retrieved using kubectl logs [pod name]):
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -Xms512m -Xmx1g -Xss256k -Dhttp.maxConnections=1000 -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5010 -Dlogging.config=classpath:logback-kube.xml
ERROR: transport error 202: gethostbyname: unknown host
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:750]

Comment: What does "breaks on step 1" mean?

Comment: @tgdavies the pod enters a crashLoopBackOff state

Comment: What do the container logs say?

Comment: @tgdavies container logs have been added to the post

Comment: You are using Java 9 or later? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50344957/java-jdb-error-transport-error-202-gethostbyname-unknown-host

Answer (score 0):

The solution was rather simple. `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:8765`

should be changed to
`-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=0.0.0.0:8765`

Comment: this should be changed in both intellij and yaml?